# assigning f a suitable 'this' value in setTimeout(f, t)

Tags: scope, this, settimeout

Is there a way to call setTimeout(f, t) such that f is assigned a 'this' of one's choice?

Answer (score 0):

I take it this is a Javascript question.  I don't know that you can do that using the native `setTimeout`, and (apparently like you) I couldn't find any documentation indicating that you can. But you can certainly roll one that does:

```js
var setTimeoutEx = function(f, t, theThis){
    return setTimeout(function(){
        return f.apply(theThis, arguments);
    }, t);
};
```

EDIT: possibly you would just use `Function.bind` to rebind `this` in `f`.

Depending on taste you might even redefine `setTimeout` in the relevant scope; I probably wouldn't, though, as it may break readers' assumptions.